# submit ajax aspforms req to modify viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, http

I'm working on a very specific web-scraping application, and it needs to login to several websites and retrieve some data from them.

I am using a WebClient that has been made aware of cookies by overriding the following method:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
    if (castRequest != null)
    {
        castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
    }
    return request;
}
```

I can login to the sites fine with regular POST/GET requests (via the appropriate download/upload methods on the webclient)

The targetted websites use ajax ASP.Net top-level forms, and there is a state variable that gets enabled after you click a button on the page. That is, when you click the button, the form gets submitted, the state gets changed, and then when it loads the response it has the information I need. The state modification at this point is also persistent. If i reload the page, or even close the tab and re-open it, the data i need will still be there because it is associated with the ASP session. As soon as the ASP session expires, you have to login and click the button again before the server will send the data I need.

I have watched the submitted form via the Chrome developer tools when clicking the button, and i re-created the form submit exactly as I saw it in the chrome network watch window, but it still does not correctly modify the viewstate.

So my question is, how can i simulate clicking this button so that the server will modify the viewstate and return the value i need.

I can not use a web-browser control for this, but I could use the html agility pack if it makes things substantially easier (although I really would like not to use an external library)

The button is defined as this:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="enterurlhere..." id="aspnetForm">
    <input type="image" name="ctl00$....." id="ctl00...." title="...." src="...." style="height:50px;border-width:0px;">
```

Comment: Can't you just create a webrequest based on the data in the `aspnetForm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your target is ASP.NET WebForms site which:

1) you must login first to navigate to the required page

2) on the required page there is an UpdatePanel that has, let's say a textbox into which you need to enter something and then submit that information and if that information is correct, you will get "what you expect"

I've done previously various crawlers, thus took one as the base but stripped down quite, well, a lot, no error logging, validation that you are logged in, validation that you are still logged in when requesting the page, HtmlAgilityPack, structure, code cleanness, user agent string randomization etc. to keep it simple for you, but you of course can enhance it :) Anyway, I've created a web project (Web Forms) in Visual Studio 2013. As you may know it has some landing pages including user registration etc. Then you have "Manage account" page, which obviously requires user to be authenticated. On that page I added another div, then inside of it I placed UpdatePanel (that makes postback ajaxified). Inside UpdatePanel I placed textbox, a button and a literal server controls. In code behind I added a click event handler for that button: if user input is equal to, let's say "secret" then put some text into the literal to indicate that operation was successful. Thus the application had to login first then get that secret text by submitting the secret phrase to "Manage account" page.

Actual fetcher:

```
using Pokemon.BL.Utils;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace Pokemon.BL
{
    sealed class UrlFetcher : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly UrlFetcher _instance;
        private CGWebClient _cgWebClient;

        private string loginPostString = "__EVENTTARGET={0}&__EVENTARGUMENT={1}&__VIEWSTATE={2}&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR={3}&__EVENTVALIDATION={4}&ctl00$MainContent$Email={5}&ctl00$MainContent$Password={6}&ctl00$MainContent$ctl05={7}";
        private string secretPhrasePostString = "__EVENTTARGET={0}&__EVENTARGUMENT={1}&__VIEWSTATE={2}&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR={3}&__EVENTVALIDATION={4}&__ASYNCPOST=true&ctl00$MainContent$btnGetSecretPhrase=Button&ctl00$ctl08=ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$btnGetSecretPhrase&ctl00$MainContent$txtSecret={5}";

        private UrlFetcher()
        {
            _cgWebClient = new CGWebClient();
        }

        static UrlFetcher()
        {
            _instance = new UrlFetcher();
        }

        #region Methods

        public void LoginToSite(string email, string password)
        {
            var loginUrl = "http://localhost:53998/Account/Login";

            byte[] response = _cgWebClient.DownloadData(loginUrl);
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

            string eventTarget = ExtractToken("__EVENTTARGET", content);
            string eventArg = ExtractToken("__EVENTARGUMENT", content);
            string viewState = ExtractToken("__VIEWSTATE", content);
            string viewStateGen = ExtractToken("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", content);
            string eventValidation = ExtractToken("__EVENTVALIDATION", content);

            string postData = string.Format(
                loginPostString,
                eventTarget,
                eventArg,
                viewState, 
                viewStateGen, 
                eventValidation,
                email, 
                password,
                "Log in"
                );

            _cgWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            response = _cgWebClient.UploadData(loginUrl, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
            _cgWebClient.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        }

        public void GetSecretPhrase()
        {
            var loginUrl = "http://localhost:53998/Account/Manage";

            byte[] response = _cgWebClient.DownloadData(loginUrl);
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

            string eventTarget = ExtractToken("__EVENTTARGET", content);
            string eventArg = ExtractToken("__EVENTARGUMENT", content);
            string viewState = ExtractToken("__VIEWSTATE", content);
            string viewStateGen = ExtractToken("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", content);
            string eventValidation = ExtractToken("__EVENTVALIDATION", content);

            string postData = string.Format(
                secretPhrasePostString,
                eventTarget,
                eventArg,
                viewState,
                viewStateGen,
                eventValidation,
                "secret"
                );

            _cgWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            _cgWebClient.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            response = _cgWebClient.UploadData(loginUrl, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
            _cgWebClient.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            _cgWebClient.Headers.Remove("X-Requested-With");

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response));
        }

        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_cgWebClient != null)
            {
                _cgWebClient.Dispose();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private string ExtractToken(string whatToExtract, string content)
        {
            string viewStateNameDelimiter = whatToExtract;
            string valueDelimiter = "value=\"";

            int viewStateNamePosition = content.IndexOf(viewStateNameDelimiter);
            int viewStateValuePosition = content.IndexOf(valueDelimiter, viewStateNamePosition);

            int viewStateStartPosition = viewStateValuePosition + valueDelimiter.Length;
            int viewStateEndPosition = content.IndexOf("\"", viewStateStartPosition);

            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                     content.Substring(
                        viewStateStartPosition,
                        viewStateEndPosition - viewStateStartPosition
                     )
                  );
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public static UrlFetcher Instance { get { return _instance; } }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

WebClient wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace Pokemon.BL.Utils
{
    // http://codehelp.smartdev.eu/2009/05/08/improve-webclient-by-adding-useragent-and-cookies-to-your-requests/
    public class CGWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private System.Net.CookieContainer cookieContainer;
        private string userAgent;
        private int timeout;

        public System.Net.CookieContainer CookieContainer
        {
            get { return cookieContainer; }
            set { cookieContainer = value; }
        }

        public string UserAgent
        {
            get { return userAgent; }
            set { userAgent = value; }
        }

        public int Timeout
        {
            get { return timeout; }
            set { timeout = value; }
        }

        public CGWebClient()
        {
            timeout = -1;
            userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            if (request.GetType() == typeof(HttpWebRequest))
            {
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = userAgent;
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = timeout;
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally run it:

```
UrlFetcher.Instance.LoginToSite("username", "password");
UrlFetcher.Instance.GetSecretPhrase();

UrlFetcher.Instance.Dispose();
```

this outputs the secret phrase into console application. Of course you will need to tweak this to make it work, for example depending on the ASP.NET version your target site is running and so on :)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I didn't actually use much/any of this code, but it lead me in the right direction.. I had my own WebClient wrapper, and I wasn't setting the useragent - i guess the website was acting differently because of that and it was messing me up. As well, I realized from your post you don't have to submit back the entire asp form, just the __* values and then the inputs that changed. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this will work server-side, because the client needs the session information. To do this you could implement an Iframe control that you could load the form in and call a server side or client side call to click the button in the Iframe and load the session information.